# Bind and trigger backbone event to a specific view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm creating an ajax upload component which consists of a progress bar for each backbone view, this is how my view template looks like.

```
<script id="view-template-dropped-file" type="text/html">
    <a><%=name %></a><span><%=fileSize%></span>
    <div class="ui-progress-bar">
        <div class="ui-progress"></div>
    </div>
</script>
```

When I drop files on my drop area I create a view for each file like this

```
for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var view = new DroppedFileView({
        model: new DroppedFile({
            name: files[i].name,
            fileSize: files[i].size
        })
    });
    var $li = view.render().$el;
    $('#droparea ul').append($li);
});
```

The drop area with some files added showing a progress bar for each file. http://cl.ly/Lf4v

Now when I press upload I need to show the progress for each file individually.

What I tried to do was to bind to an event in my DroppedFileView like this

```
initialize: function() {
    var app = myapp.app;
    app.bind('showProgress', this._progress, this);
}
```

and the _progress function

```
_progress: function(percentComplete) {
    this.$el.find('.ui-progress').animateProgress((percentComplete * 100), function () { }, 2000);
}
```

and this is how I trigger the event from the drop area view

```
xhr: function () {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total;
            app.trigger('showProgress', percentComplete);
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
}
```

of course this will not work because I listen to the same showProgress event in all views which will cause all progress bars to show the same progress.

So, is it possible to bind an event to a specified view so the progress can be updated individually or is events not a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider making the `DroppedFile` model emit the progress events. So simply instead of triggering the event on `app`, trigger it on the model instance which is being uploaded.

Your sample code doesn't mention which class holds the `xhr` method, but it would make sense to define it on the model itself. In which case the event triggering is trivial:

```
xhr: function () {
    var model = this;
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = e.loaded / e.total;
            model.trigger('showProgress', percentComplete);
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
}
```

And in view constructor:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('showProgress', this._progress, this);
}
```

**Edit based on comments:**

Even if your view structure is a bit more complicated than I assumed above, in my opinion using the `DroppedFile` model as event emitter is the way to go. If one `DroppedFileView` represents `DroppedFile`, it should reflect the state of the model  it makes sense.

Just keep track of the models in `DropzoneView`, just like (or instead of how) you do now with the files in the `DropzoneView.files`. Whether you want to have the actual AJAX request to be the responsibility of the view or refactor it to the individual models doesn't really matter.

Comment: Actually I have one view for the drop zone and one view for each dropped file so I guess trigger on the model does not work for me. I have made a fiddle for this showing the code I'm working on. http://jsfiddle.net/eLLmW/66/

Comment: @Marcus, updated my answer, it was too long for the comments. Just my $0.02